# fullcalendar after removeevents initialization don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

i'm using fullcalendar, when i render an event (i'm adding event through a modal), i'm using Ajax to insert it in the db, then i'm getting the insert_id and i'm trying to attrib the id to the event like that:

```
eventAfterRender:function( event, element, view ) { 
        $(element).attr("id","event_id_"+event._id);
}
```

But it didn't work, so, when i'm submitting in my modal, at the end i'm calling this function:

```
function getFreshEvents(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //removeEvents,
            eventSources: [
            {
                events: {
                    url: root_url + 'agenda/LoadEvenements',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {
                        start:moment( $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").start ).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
                        end:moment( $("#calendar").fullCalendar("getView").end ).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
```

But this didn't work!!

One thing works fine:

```
function getFreshEvents(){
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
        $.ajax({
            url: root_url + 'agenda/LoadEvenements',
            type: 'POST', // Send post data
            async: false,
            success: function(s){
                if(s.vide != true){
                    json_events = s;
                }
            }
        });
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', json_events);
    }
```

But as you can see, i don't send the params start and end.

Any idea?

Comment: It is not the same URL request... The first one is a GET request and the second one is a POST request. It depends on your server

Comment: yes, it's 2 ways to fetch events. The second works fine but i don't get startdate and enddate, i fetch ALL events. Too big! So i looked for a method to fetch only events in the current week. In the doc of Fullcalendar, i found this: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/
There is endParam and startParam, so i modify my code with a GET method to only fetch events i need. Since then, my fullcalendar remove all events without refetching all events after.

Comment: Can you share your server code for that request?

Comment: the POST one or the GET one?
The request works fine! Fetch works and insert works too. My problem is when i insert an event in bdd, i refetching to get event from bdd with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send the start & end date explicitly. The fullcalendar does it for you automatically by the current view's start and end time. Also you can use events instead of eventSources if only one source is filling your calendar.

So I would go for that:

```
function getFreshEvents(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: root_url + 'agenda/LoadEvenements',               
    });
}
```

Or if you insist on eventSources so:

```
function getFreshEvents(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         eventSources: [
             'root_url + 'agenda/LoadEvenements'                
         ]             
    });
}
```

Although both of the code sections will do what you want to do, I would conciser a different approach. It make no sense to reload all the events whenever a new event is being added. So when you create the event and send it to the server, also add it to the calendar with [renderEvent](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/) function by yourself. You can set the `stick` option to true for not loosing the event when you click prev and next.

Hope that helps.